# GitHub Actions triggered on pull request does not lock "Merge" Button if fails

Tags: git, github, workflow, github-actions, pull-request

For a python application, I have setup a GitHub action that runs pytest (and other tools) on each pull request to master.

When the workflow fails, I saw it in the "Check" tab on the pull request page, but I can merge my branch even if the GitHub action fails:

[image]

In my repository, settings -> branches, I created a new protection rules that matches my need, but I can't specify any status check.

All I want to do is to use my workflow to allow (or forbid) a Pull Request to be merged according to the workflow's output.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you an admin on the repo? There is [a setting that allows admins to still merge if any checks fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPfPV.png) - among other things.

Comment: Yes I am. I actually thought about that but to be sure I added a friend as a simple contributor and he was also able to merge. So it's not related I think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok so the right answer is pretty straightforward but it is not documented:

When creating a branch protection rule, you must check `Require status checks to pass before merging`  (that's what I did), AND (that's what I did not) you MUST add a status check by searching it in the search bar.

**If nothing appears, it's normal. You have to search the status check, it's the name of your job on your GitHub Action !**